# Changing a minor mistake in an older commit in git

Tags: git

What is the best way of fixing a minor mistake, a typo e.g., in an older commit instead of making a new commit that fixes it? I don't want to mess up the history with a lot of "typo-fixing" commits. I have not yet pushed the commits to anyone.

Let's say in this senario, I want to fix a code typo in January 15 commit while maintaining the other 2 commits as well.

```
commit 826da06f085664298164a4bfc9994cad109c59f8
Author: Me
Date:   Tue Jan 17 18:48:12 2012 +0800

    feature 3 working

commit d816dd97a207add63d31958c3ffba84b65681810
Author: Me
Date:   Tue Jan 16 17:47:29 2012 +0800

    feature 2 working

commit 972ded30c20692cb74ae07d0c941c43022c905bd
Author: Me
Date:   Thu Jan 15 08:48:40 2012 +0800

    feature 1 working
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
rebase -i <sha of commit PRIOR to the one you want to change>
```

then select which commit(s) you want to change, remove etc.

Answer (score 5):

I use the following scenario.

1. Fix a minor mistake
2. Commit the fix
3. git rebase -i HEAD^4

This open a vim editor (probably) with a following text

```
pick 972ded feature 1 working
pick d816dd feature 2 working
pick 826da0 feature 3 working
pick xxxxxx fix feature 1
```

change this to

```
pick 972ded feature 1 working
f xxxxxx fix feature 1
pick d816dd feature 2 working
pick 826da0 feature 3 working
```

Notice that I move "fix feature 1" commit to the second line and change **pick** to **f**.
This tells git to merge "feature 1 working" and "fix feature 1" commit to a single commit with a commit message from the first one (i.e. "feature 1 working").

"feature 2 working" and "feature 3 working" commits git leaves "untouched".
(Actually it apply this commits to a new previous history. So they'll got new ids)

Answer (score 2):

```
git rebase -i HEAD~3
```

is what you would want to do. You are the author of the 3 commits and if you didn't push it already somewhere then I think it is fine to proceed. In any other case I would recommend not to perform the action.

See [this good page for details](http://progit.org/book/ch6-4.html)

Answer (score 0):

My preferred way is to create a new branch from that problematic commit. Fixed the issues on that new branch, and commit. Then merge this new branch to the original branch. Not sure if this is what you want.